# Install a specific docker image of Couchbase

Tags: docker, couchbase

Default command always installs the latest version (currently it's 5)-

`docker run -d --name db-cb -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase`

I want to install 4.6.3; how can we specify version in above command.

https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/tags/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify version as

```
docker run -d --name db-cb -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase:4.6.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to some internet issue, below command was not working. So i got impression that it's not the right command.

Below command works -

`docker run -d --name db-cb -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase:enterprise-4.6.3`